# jQuery UI autocomplete search first char in result with Ajax source

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i stuck into problem to use jQuery UI autocomplete with Ajax response.  I cannot search result matching with first char only when use Ajax request as source.

Here what i have done :

```
$( "#date" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: function( request, response ) {
      var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
      response( $.grep('http://myajaxrequesturl.com/period_id/', function( item ){
          return matcher.test( item.label );
      }) );
  },
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `$.grep` call? You need to make an AJAX request and then filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO You should filter Your data server-side.